# Tabularx and align, gather or something else for a two line equation

Tags: equations, align, tabularx, multirow

I am trying to insert a two line equation in a tabularx environment. I managed to do it with vbox for a one line equation, but I can't seem to do it for a two line equation. I tried multirow, but I don't want to set the width of the surrounding cells with a fixed value. I would like it to look similar to the other rows with the one line equation.

This is what I want:

[image]

This was my last attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,openany,letterpaper,pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcommand\fch{0.2}
\newcommand\sch{0.35}
\newcommand\tch{0.3}
\newcommand\fich{0.15}
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|C{\fch}|C{\sch}|C{\tch}|C{\fich}|}
\hline

Acoustic Entropy Index (H) & 
\vbox{\begin{equation}
H_t H_s
\end{equation}} & 
It is the product of $H_s$ and $H_t$ (see below). It ranges between 0 and 1; 0 for pure tones and 1 for white noise. & 
\cite{Sueur2008} \\ \hline

Entropy of spectral maxima ($H_m$) & 
{\begin{align}
U_j &= \mathrm{max}(s_{i,w}), \forall w = j \\
H_m &= - \sum_{j=1}^{N_f} U_j\log_{2}U_j
\end{align}}&
The Shannon index is applied to the maximum values of each frequency bin in the spectrogram, but only in the band between 482 Hz and 8820 Hz (expanding the biophony band). $s_{i,w}$ stands for a cell in the spectrogram in the time step i and frequency bin w and $U_j$ is the maximum value in the frequency bin j. & 
\cite{Towsey2014a} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

The code produces an error.

Comment: Why not using a simpler and more readable itemized list? See [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wqKF.png)

Comment: @egreg maybe I should... this table is causing me a lot of problems.. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mis-feature of `ltablex` you could use `tabularx` or use `\keepXColumns` so that the alignments don't give errors.

However even with this, `tabularx` can't really see the width of an alignment, you get slightly better layout if you set a width for the second column using `p{..}` but fitting all this text in a table makes it very hard to see a good layout possibility.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,openany,letterpaper,pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcommand\fch{0.2}
\newcommand\sch{0.35}
\newcommand\tch{0.3}
\newcommand\fich{0.15}
\keepXColumns% \dontBreakStuff
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|C{\fch}|C{\sch}|C{\tch}|C{\fich}|}
\hline
Acoustic Entropy Index (H) & 
{\begin{equation}
H_t H_s
\end{equation}} & 
It is the product of $H_s$ and $H_t$ (see below). It ranges between 0 and 1; 0 for pure tones and 1 for white noise. & 
\cite{Sueur2008} \\ \hline
Entropy of spectral maxima ($H_m$) & 
{\begin{align}
U_j &= \mathrm{max}(s_{i,w}), \forall w = j \\
H_m &= - \sum_{j=1}^{N_f} U_j\log_{2}U_j
\end{align}}&
The Shannon index is applied to the maximum values of each frequency bin in the spectrogram, but only in the band between 482 Hz and 8820 Hz (expanding the biophony band). $s_{i,w}$ stands for a cell in the spectrogram in the time step i and frequency bin w and $U_j$ is the maximum value in the frequency bin j. & 
\cite{Towsey2014a} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}



\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|C{\fch}|p{.5\textwidth}|C{\tch}|C{\fich}|}
\hline
Acoustic Entropy Index (H) & 
{\begin{equation}
H_t H_s
\end{equation}} & 
It is the product of $H_s$ and $H_t$ (see below). It ranges between 0 and 1; 0 for pure tones and 1 for white noise. & 
\cite{Sueur2008} \\ \hline
Entropy of spectral maxima ($H_m$) & 
{\begin{align}
U_j &= \mathrm{max}(s_{i,w}), \forall w = j \\
H_m &= - \sum_{j=1}^{N_f} U_j\log_{2}U_j
\end{align}}&
The Shannon index is applied to the maximum values of each frequency bin in the spectrogram, but only in the band between 482 Hz and 8820 Hz (expanding the biophony band). $s_{i,w}$ stands for a cell in the spectrogram in the time step i and frequency bin w and $U_j$ is the maximum value in the frequency bin j. & 
\cite{Towsey2014a} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}





\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the noindent command for?

Comment: @DIANACAROLINADUQUEMONTOYA you specified that the table is `\hsize` wide (better to use `\columnwidth` actually, but same thing here) but it is at the start of a paragraph so would be indented by the paragraph indentation (usully 15pt) so would be an overfull line sticking in to the right margin

Answer (score 1):

You also can load `xltabular` a recent package by Hervert Voss, which loads `ltablex` and fs some of its problems. Simply use the eponymous environment. I slightly changed the parameters for the widths of t(he various `X` columns, so the equation numbers stay on the same line as the equations:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,openany,letterpaper,pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\mathindent}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|C{0.7}|C{1.65} |C{1.1}|C{0.55}|}
\hline
Acoustic Entropy Index (H) &
{\begin{equation}
H_t H_s
\end{equation}} &
It is the product of $H_s$ and $H_t$ (see below). It ranges between 0 and 1; 0 for pure tones and 1 for white noise. &
\cite{Sueur2008} \\
\hline
Entropy of spectral maxima ($H_m$) &
{ \begin{align}
U_j & = \mathrm{max}(s_{i,w}), \forall w = j \\\
H_m & = - \sum_{j=1}^{N_f} U_j\log_{2}U_j
\end{align} }%}
&
The Shannon index is applied to the maximum values of each frequency bin in the spectrogram, but only in the band between 482 Hz and 8820 Hz (expanding the biophony band). $s_{i,w}$ stands for a cell in the spectrogram in the time step i and frequency bin w and $U_j$ is the maximum value in the frequency bin j. &
\cite{Towsey2014a} \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]